# What's the proper (seo safe) way to blackout a site (e.g. for SOPA)?

Tags: 7

I want to safely blackout my Drupal site to raise the awareness of [SOPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSOPA_initiative/Learn_more). What's the SEO friendly way to do that?

I'm thinking of putting my site into maintenance mode and just changing the maintenance message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this post on the [Drupal Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/113325464728592995596/posts/UkCavNanLv6). It says:

> Black out your #Drupal site against #SOPA on Wednesday. Drupal's maintenance mode is [503 status](https://drupal.org/node/1044786) so it [won't hurt your SEO](http://www.seroundtable.com/sopa-blackout-google-seo-14592.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SOPA Blackout Module](https://github.com/basekamp/drupal-sopa-blackout), which will make your site look like the image below. It will also add a 503 header to preserve SE ranking.

[image]